# How to include zeromq header for C++ on Fedora?

Tags: c++, zeromq, fedora

I'm trying to compile a project that uses ZeroMQ on a virtualised Fedora instance. When I compile, it throws this error:

```
/vagrant/md_tcp_service/src/../inc/md_tcp_service.hpp:7:10: fatal error: zmq.hpp: No such file or directory
    7 | #include <zmq.hpp>
```

I assume I need to include the header file somehow, but I'm not exactly sure how. Would really appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: The path where this header is found should be defined as include directory. Depending on how you build this project (CMake, Makefile, just a terminal command) the steps can vary.

Comment: Did you install the zeromq headers and development library before?

Comment: Nope I haven't.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by running:

```
sudo yum install cppzmq-devel.x86_64
```